# Does "overwhelming" equate to "majority"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, semantics

I had a disagreement with somebody, and I am struggling to see how I could be wrong. Essentially, I referred to a representation of a certain group of people on a website as overwhelming; my exact words were "overwhelming representation of [group]". The person made the assumption that I meant "majority" because that's what "overwhelming" means in their mind. My response was that it does not have to refer to the majority, by definition, and I justified this by stating that, if it were otherwise, phrases like "overwhelming majority" would be redundant.

In conclusion, my argument can be reduced to the claim that a certain amount of things can be considered overwhelming, even if that amount does not represent the majority. I suppose this is context-dependent; in the sense that the onus is on the individual making the claim to justify their conception of a certain group of people as being "very large".

I feel somewhat confused about this, so any help from anyone would be extremely appreciated. Thank you.

****Edit**:** I didn't expect this post to receive this much attention, so thank you to everyone who's contributed. I regret the overly self-confident tone this was written in, and I apologize if it came off as arrogant. I should have put in more thought into my problem before deciding to post. I can assure you I am fully aware I am a novice when it comes to English linguistics, but really understanding the extent of this after reading everyone's responses only has me excited to continue learning.

Comment: **overwhelming** originally referred to waves swamping a boat, dumping more water than the boat could manage, causing it to capsize.  It had nothing to do with counting things. Nowdays it can express extreme degree or extent, and in contexts like "overwhelming majority" it means something like "majority by a very large margin",  not merely a slim majority.  Or you could  find something "emotionally overwhelming", say,  more than you can manage.

Comment: @TimR The thing about the boat is a supposition, not a fact: mid-14c., overwhelmen, "to turn upside down, overthrow, knock over," from over- + Middle English whelmen "to turn upside down" (see whelm). Meaning "to submerge completely" is early 15c. Perhaps the connecting notion is a boat, etc., washed over, and overset, by a big wave. Figurative sense of "to bring to ruin" is attested from 1520s. https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=whelm

Comment: Whether or not something is overwhelming **to you** has zero to do with majorities. :)

Comment: @Lambie "overwhelming" can be used to describe a situation/feeling, or a proportion. The question is about the latter, and in that case it generally means a very large majority. You can be overwhelmed by how thin the majority was.

Comment: @Barmar No, it isn't about the latter. It's about: overwhelming representation of [group].

Comment: @Lambie You're right, I've reread the question.

Comment: What may be, at least partially, the source of confusion here is that there are two groups, and thus two possible majorities. The phase 'overwhelming representation of X' is always about the overwhelming representation of X in Y. Is your question whether this phrase implies that the representation constitutes the majority of X or whether it implies that the representation constitutes the majority of Y?

Comment: @jsw29 The top answer definitely has it right in terms of its prizing of context here. I should have provided more to attempt to clarify my confusion better. This probably is a silly distinction, but the entire phrase was "an overwhelming representation of X" because I was consciously not referring to a majority group but a group whose inclusion in any capacity would be problematic, let alone its actual one, which happened to be quite large.

Comment: @Lambie: **whelmen** meaning "to capsize" is attested *circa* 1325 and later  develops extended meanings, both literal and figurative,  related to overturning; **oferwhelmen** meaning "to capsize" is attested from the mid 15th c.

Comment: @TimR Etymonon does not agree with you because this is not definitive.

Comment: @Lambie:There are far more authoritative reference works available than Etymon online, which cite the attestations.

Comment: "Conclusively, my argument can be reduced to the claim" I think you mean "In conclusion". "Conclusively" means "shown beyond doubt".

Comment: @Accumulation Made the edit. Thanks.

Comment: Without further context and a full sentence, "overwhelming representation" seems to be a poor collocation and probably wrong.

Comment: In cooking, a dish could have an overwhelming amount of salt, even though the actual proportion of salt is much less than the other ingredients.

Comment: "I am struggling to see how I could be wrong" - Well, of course you would be wrong if "overwhelming" always means a majority ;)

Comment: To clarify, did you mean the group is overrepresented? And by that, I mean *represented disproportionately* (Collins).

Answer (score 20):

"Overwhelming majority" is indeed not redundant, but for the opposite reason that you seem to think. "Overwhelming majority" means *more* than just "majority". 51% is a majority. 90% is an overwhelming majority. What "overwhelming" without "majority" means depends on the context. I would have to see more of the surrounding text to know what "overwhelming representation of [group]" means, or whether it's even idiomatic.

Comment: I see. The phrase "overwhelming majority" automatically has to do with proportions, but the use of "overwhelming" in isolation depends on the context. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I agree. The two words "overwhelming" and "majority" appear together on a regular basis in current usage, if looking to express the influence of an aggressive minority you might need something different. "The overwhelming majority voted against the measure, but there was an aggressive and overpowering minority which eventually used the media to force it to be reexamined".

Answer (score 11):

Whether "overwhelming" refers to a majority depends on the context. For instance, if you say

> The vote was overwhelmingly in favor of candidate X.

it's clear that you're talking about a majority. Not only did X receive the majority necessary to win the election, but far more than this.

On the other hand, if you say

> There was an overwhelming number of audience members at the show.

it would mean that there were too many people to fit in the theatre (i.e. "standing room only"), not the majority of possible patrons.

So in contexts where it's obvious that you're talking about a proportion, "overwhelming majority" would be redundant.

Your example of "overwhelming representation of [group]" seems ambiguous to me. It could mean that the number of people from the group accessing the website was so large that it caused the site to crash (or some other extreme reaction to their presence), or it could be interpreted as a large majority of the group are members of the site. I'd expect that the surrounding context to make it clear which situation you're talking about.

Comment: Regarding "The vote was overwhelmingly in favor of candidate X.", I would argue it's unclear what this means exactly; in particular, depending on the context it might mean an absolute majority, or it might something much weaker. For instance, if there are 100 candidates, and X is the only candidate who received more than 1% of the votes, then it makes sense to say that the vote is "overwhelmingly in favour of candidate X" even though X only received a small percentage of the votes.

Comment: @Stef True, I was assuming a majority vote as the context. Although in your example, for it to be overwhelming, the winner would have to get much more than 1% to call it "overwhelming". E.g. they get 20-30% and the rest split the remainder.

Comment: 51% vs 49% represents a majority, but not an overwhelming majority. If "overwhelming majority" were truly redundant in the context of a proportion, there would be no difference whatsoever between a majority and an overwhelming majority. But there *is* a difference, adding "overwhelming" clearly adds meaning not carried by "majority" alone. A majority is simply greater than 50%, an overwhelming majority is greater than 50% by a wide margin.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I don't think the claim is that "overwhelming" is redundant, it's that "majority" is redundant because "overwhelming" implies that. E.g. "The vote was overwhelmingly in favor of X." But as Stef points out, this depends on what kind of vote it is.

Answer (score 6):

First, there are no exact synonyms. Two words may seem to be interchangeable in all contexts, but a 'word' is distinct from another word because there must be some instances in which they aren't replaceable one for the other.

Second, the meaning of a word is not set in stone by its dictionary definition. Dictionaries are attempts at capturing meaning in the hopes of reminding a speaker/reader who already kind of knows but can't remember exact details, or a starting point for someone who has never heard/seen the word. Dictionaries notoriously stop at 'enough' and don't continue in order to give an exhaustive set of connotations and common usage contexts.

'Majority' has a very specific and, contrary to most words, pretty literal meaning: with a context of a set number, more than 50% of that number. Therefore it is easy to check against specific numbers.

'Overwhelming' is somewhat vaguer and refers more to an emotional response. It mostly means 'a surprising number'. If shoehorned into a numerical range, which cuts out a lot of its richness, it means 'more than expected'. If the expected amount is a set number, then one might infer, if one were so inclined to be so literal about things, that the number one is overwhelmed about is more than the total expected and therefore more than 100%. Which is definitely more than 51%.

One might quibble about ambiguous contexts - that is,  a cup of coffee may have an overwhelming amount of milk added, but the milk may not be a majority of the cup. The point is that the 'overwhelmingness' is not directed at the entire cup, just the amount of milk compared to the expected amount of milk.

So 'overwhelming' is related but not identical to 'majority' (more of something). An overwhelming majority is not pleonastic - it is a majority far above 50%.

Comment: _pleonastic_ TIL a new word.

Comment: I've asked for clarification, but does the OP just mean 'overrepresented'? Like Very Cherry Mixed Fruit…and all the tasteless pears are upset about it.

Comment: *"Two words may seem to be interchangeable in all contexts, but a 'word' is distinct from another word because there must be some instances in which they aren't replaceable one for the other."* <<< I would agree on principle, but it's a bold statement to make about English, which notoriously has both an anglo-saxon and a greco-latin word for everything.

Comment: I also disagree that "overwhelming majority" necessarily means a majority far above 50%.

Answer (score 2):

"Overwhelming" could have absolutely nothing to do with a "majority". In some cases they could be synonymous, but they are two completely different words.

Like:
"It was such great venue, but a small minority where so out of control that it was overwhelming"

"Most people are so easy to get along with, but there are enough that are not that it makes interactions with strangers overwhelming"

Even in exact opposition:

"It was overwhelming how few people showed up; this was supposed to be the big day"

Idk, I'm not an English teacher, lol. But they are two completely different words, that are kind of related in context.

Answer (score 0):

"Overwhelming" is an adjective (modifies a noun), and "overwhelmingly" is an adverb (modifies a verb).  "Majority" is a noun.  Because they are different parts of speech, they cannot be used interchangeably.  A noun form of this word, "overwhelmingness," is in the dictionary and means the quality of being overwhelming, but I that word would be awkward to use in regular speech.

A simple majority is defined as anything greater than 50%.  An overwhelming majority should be a lot more than 50%.  People will also use the term "a vast majority" to refer to a majority significantly over 50%, although an overwhelming majority would seem to be larger than a vast majority.

The concept of "overwhelming" has to do with the impact of whatever you are talking about.  If you put five or ten times as much salt as you need to in a dish, the taste will be overwhelmingly salty even though the majority of the content of the dish does not consist of salt.

Comment: Hi. Am I correct to assume the second occurrence of "adjective" was meant to be "adverb"?

Comment: Thank you.  I fixed it.

Comment: *"A simple majority is defined as anything greater than 50%"* << I disagree with that definition. You don't need 50% for a majority; you just need more than anyone else. For instance, if in a class of 30 students, 8 students choose German as their first foreign language, 10 students choose Spanish as their first foreign language, and 12 students choose English as their first foreign language, then you can say that the majority chose English, even though 12 out of 30 is less than 50%.

Comment: @stef The term for "the highest total, even if it's not over half" is plurality. I don't doubt some people use majority "incorrectly", which can change the meaning over time, but I think the trend is away from that -- from elections coverage more and more people are using plurality as an uncommon but everyday word.

Comment: Stef:  The American Heritage Dictionary definition of majority is:      (1) The greater number or part; a number more than half of the total. (2) The amount by which the greater number of votes cast, as in an election, exceeds the total number of remaining votes. (3) The political party, group, or faction having the most power by virtue of its larger representation or electoral strength.   

Evidently we are both correct, but your point is irrelevant to the terms "overwhelming" and "majority" being interchangeable and my explanation of why they are not interchangeable.  Thank you!